# Bootstrap 4 navigation bar displays ml-auto items stacked on each other when screen is resized

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created two navigation bars, where the one below is included in the dropdown toggle icon when screen becomes small. On the first navigation bar, I have two items pushed to the far right. When I resize the screen, I can see the hamburger icon; however, these items become stacked on each other. I know that if I use `navbar-expand` the items will be displayed properly, but then the hamburger icon won't be shown.

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- First navigation bar -->

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm bg-white">
        <div id="burger">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="border: none; background: none; outline:none;">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        </div>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="assets/logo/logo.PNG" width="160" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> </a>

        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">     <!-- the items on the right -->
            <div class="dropdown item" style="margin-top: 12px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <button class="no-style dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="notification_button">
                    <span class="icon icofont-notification text-secondary"></span>
                    
                    <div>
                        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-sm">6</span>
                    </div>
                    
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown item">
                <button class="no-style dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-offset="0, 10" style="border: none; background: none; outline:none;">
                    <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <img src="/assets/content/user.jpg" style="border-radius: 500px!important;" alt="" width="40" height="40" class="mr-1"> <i class="icofont-simple-down"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" x-placement="bottom-end">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-home"></span> Edit account</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-user"></span> User profile</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-calendar"></span> Calendar</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-settings"></span> Settings</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-logout"></span> Log Out</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- Second navigation bar -->

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: -10px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/link-1">link</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/link-2">link</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/link-3">link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

How can I display the hamburger and the two items on the right without having them stacked on each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stacked on each other because their container has the navbar-nav class apllied, which contains the property "flex-direction:column", you should apply "flex-direction:row" instead in the css, or the class "flex-row" in the html:

```
<div class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-row">     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the style

```
.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

in `_navbar.scss` is limited to a min-width of 576px using a media query.

In order to achieve your goal you can apply the style manually resulting in your items not get stacked anymore, like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
    #right-navbar {
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
</style>
<!-- First navigation bar -->

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm bg-white">
        <div id="burger">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="border: none; background: none; outline:none;">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        </div>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="assets/logo/logo.PNG" width="160" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> </a>

        <div id="right-navbar" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">     <!-- the items on the right -->
            <div class="dropdown item" style="margin-top: 12px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <button class="no-style dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="notification_button">
                    <span class="icon icofont-notification text-secondary"></span>
                    
                    <div>
                        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-sm">6</span>
                    </div>
                    
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown item">
                <button class="no-style dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-offset="0, 10" style="border: none; background: none; outline:none;">
                    <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <img src="/assets/content/user.jpg" style="border-radius: 500px!important;" alt="" width="40" height="40" class="mr-1"> <i class="icofont-simple-down"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" x-placement="bottom-end">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-home"></span> Edit account</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-user"></span> User profile</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-calendar"></span> Calendar</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-ui-settings"></span> Settings</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item align-items-center"><span class="icon icofont-logout"></span> Log Out</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- Second navigation bar -->

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: -10px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/link-1">link</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/link-2">link</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/link-3">link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The result looks like the following:

[image: Result with right items not getting stacked anymore]

Good luck!